# How to fix mongodb log when the log stops capturing events?

Tags: mongodb

I see mongodb.log file hung at a certain date and stopped logging events since then. The type of deployment I'm referring here is a sharded cluster deployed through Automation.

We could clear the log files and bounce the cluster so the mongo Automation generates new mongodb.log files but I'm not interested in doing so. I'm trying to find out what could have caused the logs to go unresponsive. Any thoughts ?

Comment: What are your specific versions of MongoDB server and O/S? What happens when the log file is "hung" -- is your `mongod` server still responding as expected? Unless the log cannot be written to (eg. disk space or permissions) I would not expect the server to stop logging. Are there any events that might correlate with the logging stopping? For example, running low (or out of) disk space or running the `logRotate` command.

Comment: Well, I solved my issue. Initially when I set up the cluster I set syslog false and later someday while working around some configuration options I changed it to true which eventually led the log files redirect to Linux syslog. I didn't notice this change for a while (2 weeks) and was wondering why my log files stopped capturing events. Now I changed it back to usual and everything's fine. 

Thank you for your response.